# how can Cocos2d-JS read txt and update the file

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am working on a game that allows users to define a "dictionary" of question/answer pairs. Then, users can import the "dictionary" to the Game Scene and practice with the questions inside the "dictionary".

The question is how can I do this with Cocos2d-JS? Or, I should use LocalStorage API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cc.sys.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and `cc.sys.localStorage.getItem(key)`